# CSS overflow-y does placed at wrong position

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a page. When the content is bigger than the actual page, my scroll-bar is not placed at the right at - there is a small but recognizeable margin to the real end. It just happens on one small page. For the content-managemnt i use wordpress. The link to the page is here http://wp.cloudstarter.de/?page_id=156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the width set as 95% on the #page. Set the width to 100% and it should take care of it.

```
#page {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove "width: 95%" from #page

Answer (score 0):

You have given width 100% to #page, just remove that width.
 is block element and by default has width 100%.

```
#page {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  /* width: 95%; */ just remove this width
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```